# Methods to determine if traffic accidents happen more frequently along sections of a highway with poor pavement?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analysis, traffic

I have a shapefile with highway pavement conditions and a point file with accidents. If I wanted to see if traffic accidents happen more frequently along sections of a highway with poor pavement conditions, what methods would I use? I was thinking spatial analysis but not exactly sure.

Comment: A quick google search for 'pavement quality accident rate spatial statistics' (without the quotes) brings up a few interesting results with some example of linear referencing - as suggested by @Maksim below.  Sometimes just knowing what to search for will get you rolling.

Comment: If the answer given provides a solution to your question don't forget to accept it by clicking the green tick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively simple method would be to [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000000q000000) your accident points to your roads, with a one-to-one nearest match. You can then run [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) (or Frequency with Advanced License) on the resulting table with the pavement condition attribute as a CASE field. That will give you a count of all accidents per pavement condition, and you can further examine that information to get the relative statistics of accidents per type vs total.

You could also use additional CASE fields for more detailed analysis if you have them - for example fatal vs non-fatal accidents *as well as* pavement type. Note that when using multiple CASE fields, the order in which you add them matters. If you wanted the breakdown by pavement type, that should be first and then fatal/non-fatal second. Having the fatal/non-fatal field first would produce a slightly differently organized table.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look into [linear referencing.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003900000001000000) This [exercise](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Exercise_4_Displaying_and_querying_route_events/00390000004n000000/) from the tutorial in particular is pretty much exactly what you are trying to do.